# Prevent page scroll function from building queue

Tags: jquery, scroll, queue

I'm working on a page that has three sections (for now). Instead of behaving like a scroll-able page, I want the page to detect the users intent to scroll (by grabbing scrollwheel data)  and automatically scroll to that section. In this way, each tier of the page is meant to be scrolled into position (covering entire window) without other tiers being visible.

The problem I'm having is that the code detects the scrollwheel events and fires the scroll function too quickly, building a queue that scrolls the page entirely in the direction defined by scroll. Basically, I can't get it to stick in the middle tier.

I've tried throttling the scroll event via this: http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/

I've also tried implementing .stop() and .clearQueue() methods. I've rewritten this code in more ways than I can remember to try to get the behavior I want.
Thanks for any help!

Here's my code:

var tier = 1    //current tier on page load

var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"

$(window).bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){

var evt = window.event || e
    evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;

```
var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta //grabs data
if(delta < 0){ //if scroll down

    checkscroll();

}

else if(tier != 1) {    //prevents tier from changing if page can't scroll up

tier = tier - 1;

scroll();

}
```

});

function scroll() {

```
if(tier == 1) {

$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#tier1').offset().top}, 1000);

}

else if(tier == 2) {

$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#tier2').offset().top}, 1000);

}

else if(tier == 3) {

$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#footer').offset().top}, 1000);

}
```

};

function checkscroll() {

```
if(tier != 3) {     //prevents tier from changing if page can't scroll down

tier = tier + 1;

scroll();

}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can calculate ranges/areas for offset().top (tier1.offset().top to tier1.offset().top+tier1.height = tier1Range, tier2.offset().top+tier2.height = tier2Range, ... ). Check on scroll if window offset().top is in the range of active tierRange. 
If true, don't scroll. If false, do the scroll.

Comment: I have thought of that and tried adding a check for position.top in the scroll argument and it didn't do the trick for me.